# Constructing a NEST/ElasticSearch query with nested properties

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm querying an ElasticSearch database (the Danish CVR registry) using NEST in C#. I'm trying to formulate a query that will query this scheme:

```
relations: [
    {
        participant: {
            key: 123123
        },
        organisations: [
            {
                organisationName: {
                    name: "some string",
                    period: {
                        from: "SOME DATE"
                        to: "SOMEDATE OR NULL"
                    }
                },
                ... more of similar objects ..
            }
        ]
    },
    .. more of similar objects ..
]
```

My problem here is that I need to find documents that have a certain participant.key value, while at the same time has a specific organisations.organisationName.name and a missing or null value in organisations.organisationName.period.to

I know I need to use a nested query to get documents that have both a null value in the to field and a certain name in the name field, but on top of that I need to also have the specific key in the particiant.key field, and this is where I'm having trouble. Note that all 3 fields that I'm checking must be within the same relations object, and the to and name fields must be within the same organisationName object.

The query without the key part as a JSON query is this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path":       "relations.organisations.organisationName",
            "score_mode": "max", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "match": { "relations.organisations.organisationName.name": "EJERREGISTER" }},
                  {"filtered": { "filter" : {
                   "missing" : { "field" : "relations.organisations.organisationName.period.to" }
                  } } }
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}
```

Hoping someone out there is apt at making these queries in the NEST Query DSL. I could also work from a pure ElasticSearch JSON query, but the .NET equivalent would be my preferred option :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I came to the conclusion that the right answer to my problem would be a query with a nested query that 1. Checks the key, and 2. has a nested query that does the other things I needed in organisation.organisationName object.

I couldn't quite verify this, however, because the database I'm querying does not have the relations-object marked as nested (and I can't change that since it's a government database)

My workaround was to retrieve all relations related to my keys, and then filtering out the remaining objects in memory, as this wasn't too much overhead in my scenario.

Edit: as a follow up, the external database I was using added the nested clause, and it worked as explained above.